# jQuery each() or (this) for a reveal/hide toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have many instances of `.wwd-extra-content-trigger` and `.wwd-extra-content` on a page, each within a `.wwd-content-each` div.

I'm trying to write some code so if you click the trigger, it expands only the extra content within it's wwd-content-each. Currently if you do this with my current code it expands all the extra content on click, rather than it's own. I know I need to use each (this) or each() but I am unsure where.

```
$('.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each .wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('span', this).text($('span', this).text() == 'navigateup' ? 'navigatedown' : 'navigateup');
    jQuery('.wwd-extra-content').fadeToggle();
});
```

Thanks in advance,
R

Comment: can you post you html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
jQuery('.wwd-extra-content').fadeToggle();
```

to this:

```
jQuery(this).closest('.wwd-content-each').find('.wwd-extra-content').fadeToggle();
```

It can most probably be optimized if you also show a bit of the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().find('.wwd-extra-content').fadeToggle()
```

should do the trick. Or you could use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: I can only go by what he has said. True, it could be further up in the DOM and that's why I provided him with the option to use closest.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact HTML layout, you could use either this:

```
$('.wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.wwd-extra-content').fadeToggle();
});
```

or this:

```
$('.wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.wwd-content-each').find('.wwd-extra-content').fadeToggle();
});
```

The first version assumes that the content trigger and the content are children of the same HTML element; the second version assumes that they share a common `.wwd-content-each` ancestor.